# UI Freeze iOS8 On saveWithBlock and FetchedResultController for defaultContext

Tags: objective-c, iphone, magicalrecord

I have a big ui freezing when having a FetchedResultController for Entity , and async storing with saveWithBlock : completion. Please help me to understand and fix this problem. Code Example , i have a singleton :

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
  [Transaction MR_importFromArray:strongArray inContext:localContext];

    } completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
        LOG_GENERAL(@"end importing");
        LOG_GENERAL(@"saved");
        if (error && failure)
        {
            failure (error);
        }
        else  if (success) {
            success();
        }
    }];
```

And initalized fetched result controller  :

```
self.fetchedResultController=[Transaction MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"postedDate" ascending:NO withPredicate:[self predicate] groupBy:@"postedDay" delegate:self.delegate inContext:self.context];
```

Please help me to understand a bug , and what i need to do to avoid this freeze , this is my bug or MagicalRecord Bug?

Comment: [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_rootSavingContext] performBlockAndWait:^{
      self.fetchedResultController=[Transaction MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"postedDate" ascending:NO withPredicate:[self predicate] groupBy:@"postedDay" delegate:self.delegate inContext:self.context]; 
   }];

Answer (score 0):

You must wait for saving context ending all tasks , and then perform fetch.
So do the fetch in this way:

```
   [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_rootSavingContext] performBlockAndWait:^{
      self.fetchedResultController=[Transaction MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"postedDate" ascending:NO withPredicate:[self predicate] groupBy:@"postedDay" delegate:self.delegate inContext:self.context]; 
   }];
```